# After installation of Ubuntu (not dual boot), how to find the drives?

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I recently clean installed Ubuntu without dual boot, so everything was erased, but now I can't seem to find where my C and D drives are located. 
Here are the results of some commands that I tried:

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track , 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/0 size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifiers: 0x000cf109

Device     Boot        Start         End       Blocks    Id  Systems
/dev/sda1   *          2048       308457471  154227712   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         308459518       312580095   2060289     5  Extended
/dev/sda5         308459520       312580095   2060288    82 Linuxswap/Solaris

mount 
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw, errors = remount - ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec, nosuid, nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw, mode = 0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw, noexec, nosuid, gid = 5, mode = 0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec, nosuid, size = 10%, mode = 0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw, noexec, nosuid, nodev, size = 5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid, nodev, user = dangmanhtruong)

sudo lsblk
NAME              MAJ:MIN   RM      SIZE    RO    TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0      0     149.1G    0    disk    
--sda1              8:1      0     147.1G    0    part   /
--sda2              8:2      0         1K    0    part
--sda5              8:5      0         2G    0    part   [swap]
```

Comment: What would constitute a C or a D drive? What would you need them for? That sounds like Windows concepts and on a **clean** install you hopefully don't have that kind of stuff around anymore.

Comment: I think you have formatted your system and forgot to make manual partition before installing ubuntu on window system.

Comment: @Raghvendra no I did not forget anything, the data was lost anyway (due to some specific circumstances)

Answer (score 0):

what is your hard disk size? are you sure you didn't erased your other partitions through installation when making new partitions? it seems that there is no other partitions on the disk so you should try recovery tools like this:
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/testdisk/

Answer (score 0):

Linux doesn't identify drives or partitions using drive letters like some versions of Microsoft DOS and Microsoft Windows.

Linux uses device names in a hierarchy.

```
Device     Boot        Start         End       Blocks    Id  Systems
/dev/sda1   *          2048       308457471  154227712   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         308459518       312580095   2060289     5  Extended
/dev/sda5         308459520       312580095   2060288    82 Linuxswap/Solaris
```

Those are 3 separate partitions present on a single physical device.  The device is known as `/dev/sda` and the partitions are number 1, 2, and 5 (sda1, sda2 and sda5).

This [answer over at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/558156/what-does-dev-sda-for-linux-mean) explains what the `sda` thing actually means.

If you had another physical drive in your machine, it would be known as `/dev/sdb`.  However, Windows has likely used C: and D: to identify partitions on the same physical drive.

Those partitions are gone, if the above output is accurate, probably because the clean Ubuntu install has erased all existing partitions and started again.

In your case, the only partition that's directly useable is `/dev/sda1` which is mounted at `/` (the root filesystem).  Everything you want is under `/`, for example, your home directory is `/home/username` for whatever your user name is.  You have a single partition which contains the entire Linux filesystem.

You access things using the `cd` command once you are logged in.  So you can change to the temporary directory, for example, by typing `cd /tmp` from anywhere, and back to your home directory by typing `cd /home/username` or `cd ~` (the tilde is expanded to `/home/username` for you).

Comment: But how do I access these neww partitions?

Comment: `/dev/sda2` is not a "real" partition, it is a partition _entry_ for an extended partition that contains only one partition, namely `/dev/sda5` (you can see from the start and end blocks). This `/dev/sda5` is apparently marked as swap space, so it cannot be used for data.